# How do I override the $message value of the UniqueFieldConstraint class?

Tags: users

I am new to Drupal 8 and I have added Core Constraint called "UniqueField" on my custom field "Customer_no" which is attached user to Entity. Below is that code which I am trying to override error Message but its not working:

```
  function devel_reg_entity_bundle_field_info_alter(&$fields, EntityTypeInterface $entity_type, $bundle) {

      if ($entity_type->id() == 'user' && isset($fields['field_customer_number_reseller_i'])) {

        $fields['field_custome_no']->addConstraint('UniqueField', []);
        //The below code not setting Custom Error Message       
        UniqueFieldConstraint::$message = "Custom Error Message";   
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message is hard-coded into `UniqueFieldConstraint`. It's a public property, so there may be a way to set it that I don't know about. However, another way to go about it is to extend `UniqueFieldConstraint`, set your own message, and tell the system to use your class instead of the original.

1. Extend the class:

   ```
   namespace Drupal\[MODULE]\Plugin\Validation\Constraint;

   use Drupal\Core\Validation\Plugin\Validation\Constraint\UniqueFieldConstraint;

   class [MODULE]UniqueFieldConstraint extends UniqueFieldConstraint {
     public $message = 'Something about an @entity_type with a @field_name and value of %value.';
   }
   ```
2. Implement [hook_validation_constraint_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.api.php/function/hook_validation_constraint_alter/8.8.x) to swap out the existing constraint for yours:

   ```
   function [MODULE]_validation_constraint_alter(array &$definitions) {
     $definitions['UniqueField']['class'] = '\\Drupal\\[MODULE]\\Validator\\Constraints\\[MODULE]UniqueFieldConstraint';
   }
   ```

Note that `[MODULE]` should be swapped out with the appropriate value, and the class should be placed in the appropriate folder for the given namespace.

**Update:** Or, as 4k4 mentioned, you can add `@Constraint` annotation to the  constraint above, creating a new constraint. This new constraint can then be explicitly attached to whatever it is that needs constraining.

Which method to use will depend on whether you want to override the `UniqueFieldConstraint` message any time it is called (the original method I outlined) or whether you want to explicitly attach the constraint to specific items (4k4's method).

Comment: Alternatively to step 2 you can add a custom constraint ID to the class annotations `@Constraint(id="MyUniqueConstraint")`, which would be discovered automatically, and you can use it without overriding the core constraint.

Comment: Updated accordingly.